# Transferring data through localhost?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, reactjs

For my college project, I'm developing an application that analyzes/detects anomalies in videos.

The backend is Python and the frontend is JS/NodeJS. I setup the backend so it runs 4 ML models and writes the outputs to 4 separate .txt files. I created a JS file that reads the .txt files and reformats the data to be saved as 4 .json files. Currently, the frontend just reads the .json files and displays the data... I run `npm start` to display the application in the browser at localhost:3000. Here is my problem:

In the application, the user can upload a .mp4 file and watch the video (react-player). I think I can setup a button interaction to execute a script that runs the backend .py file. However, I don't know how to continue from there. I need to exchange data twice: First, I need to download the video to the .py file local directory as input to the ML models. Once the models have finished running, I need to
transfer the outputs (Python list or .json format... I know how to do either) back to the application so it can be displayed to the user.

I'm reading online that I can execute data transfer using jquery and/or ajax calls? Or maybe I setup a database? I have 0 experience w/ any of that so I'd like advice on the easiest approach. If you can recommend resources that can help me learn more on the topic, that'd also be helpful.

Comment: I am confused. Perhaps it would help to draw a sketch of your architecture, what happens in the server and what in the client, and what data should be passed around where?

Comment: You can submit it with a regular form. Also, you're using react, please don't mix it with jQuery. You can create a Python server (e.g. with [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/)) and easily run the code on route hit.

Comment: I see. So you're saying I can use [web forms](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-web-forms-in-a-flask-application) to receive the user-uploaded video and Flask to send my Python code output to the localhost? I'll take it one step at a time and make a separate post if I run into any issues. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use WebSocket to transfer the files, initially after sending the video to the backend there would be quite a bit of delay for the ML model to process it and come up with the output JSON files, WebSocket would make it easier to make this communication.
(I'm not saying it's not possible to use a rest API to do the same, but it would be easier to use WebSockets)

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it.